# Detect when the app has fully loaded in ionic / angular with splashscreen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem, in my ionic project I have created a protection screen in my application, I want the protection screen to remain active while the application is fully initialized.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
```

I'm importing a timer to control the time that the splashscreen is active

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
showSplash = true;

initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();

  timer(10000).subscribe(() => this.showSplash = false); -> here is the problem

});
```

I want this

> The SplashScreen remains active until the application is fully initialized and not for a time defined by you

Comment: I'm confused. You want your 'protection screen' to go away when the splash screen goes away?

Comment: I need the splash screen to be visible while the app fully loads

Comment: Be default, `this.splashScreen.hide()` is called after Ionic has initialized, just as you show in your code. So do you have other custom initialization other than Ionic's initialization? If so, then move `this.splashScreen.hide()` to the appropriate place in your code.

Comment: Where I move this.splashScreen.hide (), I don't understand

Comment: When you say 'protection screen', are you referring to Ionic's built in 'Splash Screen'? Or are you referring to some other thing that you created yourself?

Comment: I mean the Splash Screen that I create myself. I replaced the default ionic Splash Screen with a custom one. Now, I want to know how I can make that SplashScreen hide when the APP has fully loaded and not with the time that I am telling it to last for the splashscreen

Comment: How will you know when your app has "fully loaded"? YOU have to determine that somehow in your code and then hide your splash screen when your app has reached that state. No one is going to be able to help you figure that out because we have no idea what you mean by "fully loaded" since you apparently mean something different than Ionic's provided `platform.ready()` promise.